# Pandas DataFrame: Add Column with Sum of Row Values using Column Axis indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

Looking through previously asked questions, I couldn't find the answer that helped, since my columns are generated by using a mix of both pytrends and yfinance values.

Here is the code to get the dataframe in question:

```
import yfinance as yf
from pytrends.request import TrendReq as tr

ticker = "TER"
pytrends = tr(hl='en-US', tz=360)

# =============================================================================
# Get Stock Information
# These variables are stored as DataFrames
# =============================================================================
stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
i = stock.info
stock_info = {'Ticker':ticker}
stock_info.update(i)

# =============================================================================
# Get Google Trends Ranking for our Stock
# =============================================================================
longName = stock_info.get('longName')
shortName = stock_info.get('shortName').split(',')[0]

keywords = [ticker, longName, shortName]
pytrends.build_payload(keywords, timeframe='all')
search_rank = pytrends.interest_over_time()
```

This returns a pandas dataframe for my search_rank (the first row):

```
date                | TER | Teradyne, Inc. | Teradyne | isPartial
2004-01-01 00:00:00 | 25  | 0              | 1        | False
```

What I would like to do is to drop the isPartial column and replace it with a "Rank" column, which would take the values from columns 1, 2 and 3 and add them together so it would instead look like this:

```
date                | TER | Teradyne, Inc. | Teradyne | Rank
2004-01-01 00:00:00 | 25  | 0              | 1        | 26
```

Any ideas on how I would get this accomplished would be a HUGE help!

PS: The reason I don't want to use the actual column names is because this info will change depending on the ticker. Also, I'm an extreme noob at python, and basically still learning >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop a column

```
del search_rank['isPartial']
```

Add a calculated column

```
search_rank['Rank'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[0]+row[1] + row[2], axis=1)
```

I tested your code with above modification
here is the full code

```
import yfinance as yf
from pytrends.request import TrendReq as tr

ticker = "TER"
pytrends = tr(hl='en-US', tz=360)

# =============================================================================
# Get Stock Information
# These variables are stored as DataFrames
# =============================================================================
stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
i = stock.info
stock_info = {'Ticker':ticker}
stock_info.update(i)

# =============================================================================
# Get Google Trends Ranking for our Stock
# =============================================================================
longName = stock_info.get('longName')
shortName = stock_info.get('shortName').split(',')[0]

keywords = [ticker, longName, shortName]
pytrends.build_payload(keywords, timeframe='all')
search_rank = pytrends.interest_over_time()
del search_rank['isPartial']
search_rank['Rank'] = search_rank.apply(lambda row: row[0]+row[1]+row[2] , axis=1)

print(search_rank)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Date        TER  Teradyne, Inc.  Teradyne  Rank
2004-01-01   25               0         1    26
2004-02-01   25               0         1    26
2004-03-01   29               0         1    30
```